# ViewPager with OnClickListener

Tags: android

I have this ViewPager:

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapterMain extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    Activity activity;
    com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    List<SlidingFeedItemMain> lFeedItemsMain;
    SlidingFeedItemMain slidingFeedItemMain;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    WindowManager windowManager;

    public CustomSwipeAdapterMain(Context context, Activity activity, List<SlidingFeedItemMain> lFeedItemsMain,
                                  FragmentManager fragmentManager, WindowManager windowManager) {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.lFeedItemsMain = lFeedItemsMain;
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        this.windowManager = windowManager;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lFeedItemsMain.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_sliding_item, container, false);

        if (imageLoader == null) {
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        }

        //region FindViews
        TextView textViewtext = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView textViewTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        TextView textViewQuotations = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuotations);
//        TextView textViewAuthor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAuthor);
        final ImageView imageViewtext = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);
        final ProgressBar progressBarFeedItem = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBarFeedItem);
        final CircleImageView profilePic = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        final ImageView imageViewLike = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewLike);
        final RelativeLayout relFullFeedItem = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relFullFeedItem);
        //endregion

        //region Set text color in relation to theme
        textViewtext.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Black));
        //endregion

        if (container.isShown()) {
            //region set data to views
            slidingFeedItemMain = lFeedItemsMain.get(position);
            progressBarFeedItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            profilePic.setId(Integer.parseInt(slidingFeedItemMain.getStrUserId()));
            container.setTag(2);
            container.setId(3);
            textViewtext.setText(slidingFeedItemMain.getStrtext());
            textViewName.setText(slidingFeedItemMain.getStrUsername());
            textViewTime.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                    Long.parseLong(slidingFeedItemMain.getStrTimestamp()),
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE));
            textViewQuotations.setText(slidingFeedItemMain.getText() + " " + activity.getString(R.string.text));

            if (slidingFeedItemMain.getStrtextImageName().equals("null")) {
                imageViewtext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBarFeedItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                if (!slidingFeedItemMain.getStrtextImageName().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                    loadGif(imageViewtext, URLs.BASE_URL_START +
                            slidingFeedItemMain.getStrtextImageName() + URLs.BASE_URL_ENDE, progressBarFeedItem);
                    Log.e("ID", "is: " + slidingFeedItemMain.getStrtextImageName());
                } else {
                    loadImage(imageViewtext, URLs.BASE_URL_IMAGES + slidingFeedItemMain.getStrtextImageName(), progressBarFeedItem);
                }
                loadImage(profilePic, URLs.BASE_URL_IMAGES + slidingFeedItemMain.getStrProfileImageName(), null);
            }

            //endregion
        }

        //region click listeners
//        profilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Intent i = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
//                Log.e("TAG", "user " + v.getId());
//
////                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
////                    profilePic.setTransitionName(activity.getString(R.string.transition_name_profilePic));
////
////                    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
////                            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, profilePic, profilePic.getTransitionName());
////                    ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, i, options.toBundle());
////                } else {
////                    activity.startActivity(i);
////                    activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.gehnachlinks, R.anim.stay);
////                }
//            }
//        });
//        imageViewLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Toast.makeText(context, "LIKE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                moveViewToScreenCenter(imageViewLike, relFullFeedItem);
//            }
//        });

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("BLA","asa");
            }
        });
        //endregion



        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    private void setlAuthors(int idOftext) {
        AuthorsItem item;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            item = new AuthorsItem();
            item.setStrUsername("hallo");
            lAuthors.add(item);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void moveViewToScreenCenter(final ImageView view, RelativeLayout relativeLayout) {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight();

        int originalPos[] = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(originalPos);

        int xDest = dm.widthPixels / 2;
        xDest -= (view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2);
        int yDest = dm.heightPixels / 2 - (view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2) - statusBarOffset;

        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, xDest - originalPos[0], 0, yDest - originalPos[1]);
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        anim.setFillEnabled(true);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.from_top);
                view.startAnimation(animation1);
                view.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green));
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void loadImage(final ImageView imageView, String url, final ProgressBar progressBar) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .asBitmap()
                .error(R.drawable.error_image)
                .thumbnail(0.1f)
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        if (progressBar != null && progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);
    }

    private void loadGif(final ImageView imageView, String url, final ProgressBar progressBar) {
        Glide.with(activity)
                .load(url)
                .thumbnail(0.1f)
                .error(R.drawable.error_image)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> animation) {
                        super.onResourceReady(resource, animation);
                        //check isRefreshing
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                        if (progressBar != null && progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

The main thing is the region OnClickListeners. I would like to add an onClick Listener to my full item of the PagerAdapter. I tried to remove any onclicklisteners but it doesn't work as well...

How can I add an onClick Listener to the full item?

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the listener on the ViewPager which uses the CustomSwipeAdapterMain?

```
adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapterMain(inflater,container);
myViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

myViewPager.setOnClickListener(new ViewPager.OnClickListener() {
    // code here
});
```